# How to prevent hiding time after setting datepicker option?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datetimepicker

I've used this addon for adding time picker to jQuery UI datepicker - [date time picker](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/)

My inputs after loading have this state: `2014-04-09 19:13`, for example.
Then I initialize datetimepicker using this code:

```
var timeFormat = "HH:mm";
var dateFormat = "yy-mm-dd";
$('.datepicker').datetimepicker({
    timeFormat: timeFormat,
    dateFormat: dateFormat
});
```

Then I try to initialize min and max date range for two inputs:

```
   var closePreRegistration = $('#ClosePreRegistrationDate');
    var openPreRegistration = $('#OpenPreRegistrationDate');
    closePreRegistration.datetimepicker("option", "minDateTime", openPreRegistration.datepicker('getDate'));
    openPreRegistration.datetimepicker("option", 'maxDateTime', closePreRegistration.datepicker('getDate'));
```

But after this initialization(actually after setting any option) my inputs are reset to this format:

```
2014-04-09 without time.
```

After changing time again format will be changed to correct format, but this no resolve my problem.

How to fix this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved this problem by manually updating time after setting minDate or maxDate option.

For initializing ranges I've created function:

```
function initDateTimeRanges(first, second) {
    var minDate = first.datetimepicker('getDate');
    var maxDate = second.datetimepicker('getDate');
    second.datetimepicker('option', 'minDate', minDate);
    second.datetimepicker('setDate', maxDate);
    first.datetimepicker('option', 'maxDate', maxDate);
    first.datetimepicker('setDate', minDate);
}
```

And use it in this way:

```
initDateTimeRanges(openPreRegistration, closePreRegistration);
initDateTimeRanges(showStartTime, showEndTime);
```